# Why is solve using all cores?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

If I run this simple yet intensive command in R

```
base::solve(matrix(rnorm(1e4 * 1e4), nrow=1e4))
```

I can follow through my task manager (htop) that at a certain point all of my CPU threads get used. Why is this happening? Shouldn't just 1 be used? This behavior makes the implementation of parallel functions such as `mclapply` and `parLapply` ineffective, as all my resorces get used no matter what limits I set.

It might be relevant to know I am running R 3.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu.

Comment: you can do sessionInfo() to check the blas version, you can check this out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf, so depending on the blas version, you can search on how to restrict the cores

Comment: @user2554330, it does help to understand that parallel BLAS is the default, though I am still left wondering why that is the default behavior, since it conflicts with the expected behavior of the mentioned parallel functions (which are also part of base R).